# sed and regex to prepend line

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I'm trying to find a way to search in a  files and add a line before the a string
I want to search for

```
xxx =  text() // '=' folowed by space or not then  'text()'
```

if found :

add before this line

```
new text
```

in other word i want this

```
xxx =  text()
```

to be this :

```
new text
xxx =  text()
```

i tried this

```
find /var/www/users/ \( -name '*.py'   \)  -type f  -exec sed -i 's|\s+\=\s+\text()|new text|i' {} \;
```

Comment: Sed insert command is your friend: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-41

Comment: i'm using -i my problem is with the regex

Comment: the `-i` argument to sed tells it to edit files in place, not insert above matched expression. The trailing tells it to be a case-insensitive match....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this, I suppose:

```
find -iname '*.py' -and -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/= *text()/ i new text'
```